# How to uncomment line with Ansible replace module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

It's very common for vanilla configurations files to have settings commented out in default configuration files. For example

```
#HEAP_SIZE=2g
```

How do I remove the comment character, "#" in this case, with the Ansible replace module?

```
- name: Uncomment out HEAP_SIZE
  replace:
    dest: //etc/some_path/app.conf
    replace="what to put here to remove #???"
    regex="#HEAP_SIZE=2g"
```

Resulting in

```
HEAP_SIZE=2g
```

Comment: Have you considered templating out the entire configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lineinfile` for your task:

```
- name: Uncomment parameters
  lineinfile:
    dest: app.conf
    regexp: (?i)^\s*#\s*({{ item }}.*)
    line: \1
    backrefs: yes
  with_items:
    - heap_size
    - aNoThEr_setting
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
replace: "HEAP_SIZE=2g"
```

You'd also want to make sure it's from the beginning of the line.

Generally for this use case `lineinfile` module fits better.

Comment: I know I could've done that, but if I have multiple lines to replace, I'd have to write a task for each line, with a corresponding replace value. I'm looking for something that will remove the "#" character.